# AngularJS Big Issue 1.1.5 Upgrade to 1.3.8 (must be simple) :/

Tags: angularjs, upgrade

I have absolutely no clue anymore what could be wrong here.

Using the Version 1.1.5 everything works flawless.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.1.5/angular.min.js"></script>
```

Upgrading to 1.3.8 screws my whole application.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.8/angular.min.js"></script>
```

Getting this error Argument 'ContactControllerHeading' is not a function, got undefined

.html

```
<html ng-app="myApp" >
<body>
<div ng-controller="ContactControllerHeading">
...
lots of cool stuff here :)
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

.js

```
var myApp  = angular.module('myApp', []);

  function ContactControllerHeading($scope,$http) {

     $scope.Home = function() {
             ...
             lots of cool stuff :)
      }

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a breaking change in Angular 1.3: you no longer can create controllers using global function (function not associated with any module)

Just a minor change, instead of defining controller in global scope, just define it in your app:

```
myApp.controller("ContactControllerHeading", function ($scope, $http) {
   //controller code
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Angular 1.3 no longer supports functions to stand as controllers by default. See `$controllerProvider.allowGlobals()` ([ref](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/provider/$controllerProvider)). You will have to call this function from a module `config()` function to enable this feature. Or better, convert your code to the current practice of using

```
angular.module(...)
    .controller('ContactControllerHeading', ['$scope','$http',function($scope,$http){...}]);
```